# Adding footnote in PDF through iText7 in Java

Tags: java, itext7

I would need to produce some footnotes within a PDF file through iText 7.0.2 API with Java. I used to do it with Anchor and Chunk objects with previous iText versions, but with iText7 I did not manage to find a good approach...

Does anyone have a good code snippet?

Comment: The link for the iText7 examples regarding headers and footers :http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/clone-page-events-headers-and-footers

Comment: Hi, can you share your `iText5` code? I wonder, did you have a fixed place for footnotes in the bottom of each page? Did you use `Anchor` in order for the numbers to be clickable?